# How to pull and push code from computer A to computer B with git

Tags: git

computer A ----- computer B

on A:
        git checkout -b B1

on B:
        git checkout -b b1

Now I want to pull and push code to B's b1 branch from A's B1 branck.
And the same I need to pull and push code to A's B1 branch from B's b1 branch.

How can I do ? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you must have one of the computers setup to be a git server, or have a server that both computers can sync to.

The easist solution would probably be to just setup a [bit bucket](https://bitbucket.org/) account and setup both computers to sync to a private repo there.

Otherwise, you can look at setting up one of the [computers as a server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) (Linux recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Git has central repository. Everything is save on central location/Server

Please follow the below steps

For pull the code

1. `git stash --For minimize the merging issue`
2. `git pull`

For push the code

1. `git add "filePath"`
2. `git commit`
3. `git push`

Answer (score -1):

You should not push to a non-bare git repo.

A non-bare repo has a working tree and an index. Pushing affects the index and not the working tree. If you push to a non-bare repo, the index will be inconsistent with the working tree.

Thus, if you want to develop on two separate machines, you would need a third repo setup as a bare repo. This is what those online services like BitBucket and GitHub do. Alternatively, you can set up a third repo locally that is bare on machine A, machine B, or another machine, C.